# How can I calculate the Z value of triangles?

Tags: graphics, 3d

I am trying to implement a Z-buffer (depth buffer) for a polygon rasterization algorithm. All of my polygons are triangles and I understand that three points (x,y,z) that make up a triangle also form a plane. If I have the (x,y,z) values of the verices, how would I calculate the depth of every position on the face of the triangle?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGl or WebGl a z-buffer is applied just after [rasterization](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/images/Graphics3D_Rasterization.png) i.e. for each pixel, not for each vertex of a triangle. In this case you need to save z-value for each pixel and then just get a pixel this max z-value. This is done automatically in [pipeline](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/elementLinks/fig1_5.jpg).

If you wanna calculate a z-buffer just for vertices you need your own algorithm. For example just getting max z-value of triangle's vertices and sort triangles by this value.

Also check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhwg_O5HBwQ) for more info.

Comment: This gives no useful information. “This is done automatically” - the author isn’t asking if it’s done automatically in OpenGL, they’re asking how to do it themselves in a software renderer. You also mix up the painter’s algorithm and z buffering at the end